# RealmResults findAllAsync() returns nothing

Tags: android, realm

I am new to Realm and I have a problem.

I was able to make some writes using realm. 
The problem is that when I try get the RealmResults using

```
mResults = mRealm.where(Player.class).findAllAsync();
```

it returns nothing.  But when I use

```
mResults = mRealm.where(Player.class).findAll();
```

it returns the records.

Can I have some help? Thanks!

Comment: maybe not have any players ? u are sure `instanced` `Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();`

Comment: Hello @marlonpya. Yes I get the default instance. Using findAll() returns the records. FindAllAsync() returns nothing!

Comment: `Log.d("CODE_", mResults.toString());` Maybe ur `RealmResult` is `empty` add Search "CODE_" in ur AndroidMonitor

Comment: Hello @MehmetKologlu. I use version 2.3.1

Comment: Documentation is saying that that's what should happened... It also states how to get the values... Did you at least tried to read it?

Comment: You should probably read the documentation before asking a question here. It is supposed to return empty values.

Comment: Not null,  empty results

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/2.3.1/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#findAllAsync--
Here, so you get the hang of it

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try to search the documentation.

Comment: Guys thanks! Now it works!

Comment: RealmChangeListener is called when the async query is complete.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, `findAllAsync()` **always** returns an empty result.  That's what makes it asynchronous!  Register a `RealmChangeListener` to receive the asynchronous result.